# Disabling cronjob in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, cron, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl, kubernetes-cronjob

I have scheduled an application to run as a `CronJob` in Kubernetes. When there is a code change, I'm also changing the image of the `CronJob`.

I'm looking for an option where I can disable the currently running `CronJob` and deploy a new `CronJob` with the latest image version.

How can I disable a `CronJob` in Kubernetes without deleting its `Deployment`?

Comment: Kubernetes docs for cronjob [schedule suspension](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#schedule-suspension)

Answer (score 248):

If you want to suspend cronjob via patch, use:

```
kubectl patch cronjobs <job-name> -p '{"spec" : {"suspend" : true }}'
```

Comment: I am trying to suspend using above command but getting error

error: unable to parse "'{spec": yaml: found unexpected end of stream

Comment: `kubectl patch cronjobs <job-name> -p '{\"spec\" : {\"suspend\" : true }}'`

Comment: @Zhongxia Zhou patch with suspend false

Comment: To suspend all the cronjobs at one go
`kubectl get cronjobs | grep False | cut -d' ' -f 1 | xargs kubectl patch cronjobs -p '{"spec" : {"suspend" : true }}'`

Comment: I can't make it work. I get the following error: "error: unable to parse "'{\"spec\"": yaml: found unexpected end of stream". Am I supposed to change this command in some way (apart from replacing <job-name> with the name of the cronjob)?

Comment: @idubnori, there's no need to escape double quotes when wrapping the whole payload in single quotes.

Comment: @Subbu not sure if the best solution but it works for me on Windows, I had the same issue. As you see it seems the that there is a quote that seems to be automatically added, which brakes the json parsing. I used the following command `kubectl patch cronjobs <job-name> -p {\"spec\":{\"suspend\":true}}`  by escaping the quotes and removing the whitespaces. Looks like a terminal problem, but to time to search for the proper solution now

Comment: What happen if one cron is running ?

Answer (score 28):

```
kubectl patch cronjobs job-name -p '{"spec" : {"suspend" : true }}'
```

Answer (score 25):

Edit your current cronjob resource to include the [.spec.suspend field and set it to true](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/#suspend). Any currently running jobs will complete but future jobs will be suspended.

If you also need to stop currently running jobs, you'll have to delete them

Answer (score 20):

You can use something which will be valid with respect to Cron Job format but actually that date should not appear anytime in calendar date like 31 Feb.

```
* * 31 2 *
```

Comment: Creative, but still a workaround. Caution: does not work on other planets.

Comment: seems not to work reliably cronjob still executed with closest valid date on our cluster

Answer (score 6):

**Option 1 with command line**

```
$ kubectl patch cronjobs $(kubectl get cronjobs | awk '{ print $1 }' | tail -n +2) -p '{"spec" : {"suspend" : true }}'
```

**Option 2 with command line:**

```
$ kubectl get cronjobs | grep False | cut -d' ' -f 1 | xargs kubectl patch cronjobs -p '{"spec" : {"suspend" : true }}'
```

**Option 3 creating resource quotas. I believe that is the cleaner option.**

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
# https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/#object-count-quota
apiVersion: v1
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  name: limit-generic-resources
spec:
  hard:
    pods: "0"
    count/persistentvolumeclaims : "0"
    count/services : "0"
    count/secrets : "0"
    count/configmaps : "0"
    count/replicationcontrollers : "0"
    count/deployments.apps : "0"
    count/replicasets.apps : "0"
    count/statefulsets.apps : "0"
    count/jobs.batch : "0"
    count/cronjobs.batch : "0"
EOF
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's arguably the simplest way you can `patch` **multiple** `CronJobs` (and other patch-able objects like `Deployments` or `Pods`):

```
kubectl patch $(kubectl get cronjob -o name | grep my-filter) -p '{"spec" : {"suspend" : true }}'
```

Notice the use of `-o name` which simplifies getting a list of objects (here: `CronJobs`) names to process (without the need to parse a table with `awk`).

You can patch all of them at once or just a subset of names restricted to those meeting filtering criteria (here: containing `my-filter`).

Answer (score 1):

You can either use patch command like below -

`kubectl patch cronjobs <cron-jon-name> -n <namespace> -p '{"spec" : {"suspend" : true }}'`

or you can first get the cronjob resource yaml -
`kubectl get cronjobs <cron-jon-name> -n <namespace> -o yaml > cronjob.yaml`

Edit yaml file under spec section with suspend to true.